# Selecting Outlook Express identity using code

Tags: c++, api, interface, outlook

This code:

```
TComInterface<IStoreNamespace> pStore;
if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StoreNamespace, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IStoreNamespace, (LPVOID*)&pStore)))
    {
    if (SUCCEEDED(pStore->Initialize(Form1->Handle, 1)))
        {
        }
    }
```

Creates `IStoreNamespace` interface. But it uses default identity of Outlook Express. `Initialize` is supposed to offer a choice of identities if the second parameter is `1` as above (if it is `0` it uses default identity).

The documentation here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says this:

> If the value of dwReserved is 0, the namespace will initialize using
>   data associated with the default user identity. If the value of
>   dwReserved is 1, the user will be asked to select a user identity to
>   initialize.

The only way to use another identity is to manually switch it.

Is is possible to choose identity programatically or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some examination it appears that there is no possibility to switch identity from my program. The only thing that is available is calling `IStoreNamespace::Initialize` method as used above, with second parameter (`DWORD dwReserved`) set to either `0` which uses default identity or `1` which opens Outlook Express window if identity is logged out and requires a password or does not show anything if identity does not require password.

So as it appears, automatic switching of identities is not possible using this Interface.